# Factory not registered: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am following Michal Hartls Rails tutorial Chapter 7. I have installed the Factory girl gem. I keep getting this error when I run  my test

```
Failures:

 1) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.66336 seconds 42 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:14 # UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
```

Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
  gem "autotest-growl", "~> 0.2.16"
  gem "autotest-rails", "~> 4.1.2"
  gem "rspec", "~> 2.9.0"
  gem 'rspec-rails',  '2.9.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
  gem "spork",  '0.9.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem "factory_girl", "~> 3.2.0"
end
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', :platform =>
```

My user_controller_spec.rb is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  render_views

  describe "GET 'show'" do
    before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
    end
  end
end
```

My factories.rb is

```
FactoryGirl.create :user do |user|
  user.name                   "Mark Brown"
  user.email                 "mbrown@yahoo.com"
  user.password               "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
end
```

I changed

```
Factory(:name)
```

to

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

on line 10 in my `user_controller_spec.rb` becuase I was getting a deprication warning. I thought that would fix it but now im just getting.

```
Factory not registered: user
```

Can someone tell me what going on?

Answer (score 54):

I have already fixed it.

The solution was to change `gem 'factory_girl'` to `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same error when I first used FactoryGirl in that Chapter and all I needed to do was to restart the server and Spork if you're using it. Hope it helps

Comment: Same here, restarted both rails server and guard/spork and then the tests pass. That's a tad annoying.

Comment: Same issue & fix for zeus users.

Answer (score 6):

what if you define factory first, not create it?
try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name                  "Mark Brown"
    email                 "mbrown@yahoo.com"
    password              "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need the gem 'factory_girl_rails' under the test group

Comment: Worked for me. I accidentally used gem 'factory_girl' instead of 'factory_girl_rails'

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile you should replace with this

```
gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
```

instead of

```
gem "factory_girl", "~> 3.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using pry as my IRB.
When I removed it from my gems I was able to get Factory girl to work properly using.

```
rails c -e test

irb ->  FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Maybe someone can explain how to get this working using pry.